# Panel in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working about Chrome Extension . I read a lot in Chrome developer but no result . My idea is load a html file to panel at right-bottom browser (or any position I liked) to show videos .I cannot use popup because it will be disappeared if i click anywhere. 
Except popup,buttons on menu bar , **how can i create a panel in chrome browser ?**

Comment: Take a look at an approach in [Panel Tabs Extension](https://github.com/lnikkila/chrome-panel-tabs).

Comment: I never know that before :) But my purpose is creating panel for my extension , its not pc software  ... Thank you :)

Comment: Just in case: that wasn't a "software" but also an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can inject the `html` in the `tab` where you want to show the html. See this answer how to inject `html` :

   [Inject HTML into a page from a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334054/inject-html-into-a-page-from-a-content-script)
2. Use your own `css` as `content script` to position your element.
3. I assume you will be showing video in loaded html from external servers. But chrome extension do not allow you to reference external resources in your html. So you will need to download the video with response type `blob` and just set `src` of video element to this blob using `window.URL.createObjectURL`

Comment: wc, If you found my answer helpful plz approve and upvote.