# Chrome extension inject HTML modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

I am trying to use a Chrome extension to inject an [html](/questions/tagged/html) modal popup (like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) one: uses [css](/questions/tagged/css), [js](/questions/tagged/js), and [html](/questions/tagged/html)). Basically, I have [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) to send an announcement to the background file, and it has successfully triggered a function. I want that function, though, to be able to inject the modal popup and show it on the screen. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need to provide your code so we can see what you're doing and where you're stuck.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Hey @Oliver Leopold, did you found any solution, If so Please tell me what it is, i am in the same situation.

Answer (score -1):

[Previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334054/inject-html-into-a-page-from-a-content-script), use content.js in chrome extension to inject markup into the dom.

Comment: Modals are a different issue. You will most likely want the modal to look the same across different sites, how do you do this without having the site's css interfere?