# How can I fetch a local html file within a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to get my extension working on chrome (works on firefox with manifest v2) but I keep getting this same error.

```
GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @   main.js:5
```

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at main.js:5:1
(anonymous) @   main.js:11
Promise.catch (async)       
(anonymous) @   main.js:10
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with the manifest / CSP because it has to do with the fetch function and chrome.runtime.getURL seems to be working but I'm not sure.

```
.
├── main.js
├── manifest.json
└── menu.html
```

menu.html

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

main.js

```js
const localURL = chrome.runtime.getURL('menu.html');
console.log(localURL);


fetch(localURL)
  .then(resp => resp.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [
          "main.js"
        ],
        "web_accessible_resources": {
          "resources": [
            "menu.html"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

At first I thought it could be a problem with chrome.runtime.getURL but I logged that and it displays:

`chrome-extension://<extension_id>/menu.html`

I've also basically replicated https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378406/22896050 and still getting the same errors.

When I go to that link, it brings me to a page that renders the correct html.
Maybe fetch is changing the localURL to chrome-extension://invalid/ for some reason? Does anyone know how to fix this?

**UPDATE**
It was the manifest ( I made a mistake on the structure and forgot to add the "matches" field )

Here's the fixed version:

```json
{
    "name": "Extension Name",
    "description": "Extension Description",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [
          "main.js"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": ["menu.html"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
      }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for `web_accessible_resources`? yours doesn't look right. In fact, your manifest doesn't look right. Can you double check you've posted a valid manifest.

Comment: @JaromandaX what would the OP understand from `your manifest doesn't look right` :D

Comment: @JaromandaX  I looked over the documentation again and I messed up the manifest structure + forgot to add the "matches" property.  I'll update the question with the fixed manifest.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) your web_accessible_resources is in the wrong place (inside another section), pull it outside so it's on the same level like all other sections. 2) Add `matches` inside web_accessible_resources as shown in the documentation.

Comment: Hey, you figured it out!  That always feels nice.

Comment: @JaromandaX not quite. You can be nice to the person and at least mention that some parts of the manifest structure are not correct. It is not about spoon feeding, it's about being helpful. `just posted a garbage one here` is also not very pleasant.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica - that comment was directed at you, not the OP. and there's nothing wrong with my original comment that actually was met with *Thanks for your help!* from the OP ... you know the saying that starts ... "You can give a man a fish ..." ?

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I guess we have different styles of teaching.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica - My comment wasn't actually meant to "teach" - I seriously thought OP didn't post his ACTUAL manifest file since he mentioned it working in Firefox - I just re-read question and see now that Firefox was using manifest V2 though - so, it was just a happy coincidence

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, sorry, I think I am the one that had too much coffee at this hour

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica there is no such thing :D